# Как установить паузу и переход к другой ссылке во время парсинга на php?

Tags: php, парсер

Парсинг осуществляется с помощью PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$urls = array(

'http://sitename/1.html',
'http://sitename/2.html',
...
'http://sitename/98.html',
'http://sitenamey/100.html'

);

foreach($urls as $urlsItem){
$output = curl_init();
curl_setopt($output, CURLOPT_URL, $urlsItem);//отправляем адрес страницы
curl_setopt($output, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt ($output, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($output, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($output, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
$out .= curl_exec($output);
curl_close($output);
}

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($out);
```

Далее работает с $html и разбиваем его на составляющие.

На данный момент скрипт обращается сразу ко всему ссылкам в массиве и получает контент. Есть возможность сделать так, чтобы он обращался к ссылкам в массиве по очереди и переходил к следующей после обработки предыдущей через заданное время в мсек или сек?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver
Не изобретайте велосипеды

Comment: @АндрейТаланин селениум-то здесь зачем?

Answer (score 2):

Можно как-то так:

```
foreach($urls as $urlsItem){
    $output = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($output, CURLOPT_URL, $urlsItem);//отправляем адрес страницы
    curl_setopt($output, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($output, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt($output, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($output, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    $out .= curl_exec($output);
    curl_close($output);
    usleep(1000000); //задержка в 1 сек
}
```

Comment: Если уж одна секунда можно и просто `sleep`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте DOMDocument для этого.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$doms = array();
foreach($urls as $url){
    if($dom->load($url)) {
        $doms[] = $dom;
    }
}
echo'<pre>',
print_r($doms, true),
'</pre>';
```